# Como inicializar objetos já declarando valores?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Por exemplo nesse código:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
            Point p = new Point();
    }
}

class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Há um modo de declarar valores à `x` e `y` já enquanto se executa o comando `new`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode tentar dessa forma, criando um construtor que receba os parâmetros e atribuindo-os da forma abaixo:

```
class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Depois, é só iniciar já passando os valores:

```
Point p = new Point(4, 8);
```